# Simple Newsletter Signup form PHP

Tags: php, forms, newsletter

I have a simple "newsletter signup" form .php script that I am trying to edit.

I want the script to work exactly as it does at the moment but without the "name" input box.

I just want the "email" input box, with a message if the email is not valid and a response if the submission was successful.

The .php doc is writing to a .txt file on my server.

my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function trim(str){str = str.replace(/^\s*$/, '');return str;}
    function signup() { 
var email   = trim($F("email"));
var name    = trim($F("name"));
//EMAIL VALIDATION
var goodEmail = email.match(/\b(^(\S+@).+((\.com)|(\.net)|(\.edu)|(\.mil)|(\.gov)|(\.org)|        (\.info)|(\.sex)|(\.biz)|(\.aero)|(\.coop)|(\.museum)|(\.name)|(\.pro)|(\.arpa)|(\.asia)|(\.cat)|        (\.int)|(\.jobs)|(\.tel)|(\.travel)|(\.xxx)|(\..{2,2}))$)\b/gi);
apos=email.indexOf("@");dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");lastpos=email.length-1;
var badEmail    = (apos<1 || dotpos-apos<2 || lastpos-dotpos<2);
if (name=="") {
    $("myResponse").style.display="inline";                 //3 lines to         show and style the error message
    $("myResponse").style.color="red";                      // there are more ways to do it using css classes for example.
    $("myResponse").innerHTML="Please enter your name";     // you could also make an error function.
    $("name").clear(); $("name").focus();                                           // clear the field and put cursor inside
    return false;
    /*  YOU CAN REPEAT THE ABOVE ELSE IF BLOCK IF YOU HAD OTHER FIELDS IN YOUR FORM, 
        LIKE LAST NAME, ADDRESS ETC. AS AN EXAMPLE SEE HOW THE NAME IS HANDLED AND  REPEAT
    */
}
else if (email=="" || !goodEmail || badEmail) {
    $("myResponse").style.display="inline";             //3 lines to show and style the error message
    $("myResponse").style.color="red";
    $("myResponse").innerHTML="Please enter a valid email";
    $("email").focus();
    return false;
}
else {
    //YOU MAY WANT TO CHANGE THE URL IN THE LINE BELOW
    var url = "optIn.php";
    var params =  $("subform").serialize();
    new Ajax.Request(url, {onComplete:showResponse, onException:showException,  onFailure:showException, asynchronous:true, method:'post', evalScripts:false, postBody:params});
    $("submit", "myResponse").invoke('hide');   // Hide the buttom and the message
    $("loading").show();                        // show the loading     image.
    return false;
}
}
function showResponse(req)  {
    $("loading").hide();
    $("myResponse").innerHTML=req.responseText; //Writes the "Thank you" message that comes     from optIn.php and styles it.
    $("myResponse").style.display="inline";
    $("myResponse").style.color="blue";
    $("submit").show();
    $("name", "email").invoke('clear'); 
}
function showException(req) {
$("myResponse").innerHTML=req.responseText;
alert("An error occured while talking to the server. Please try again.");
$("loading", "myResponse").invoke('hide');
$("submit").show();
$("name", "email").invoke('clear');    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hog</h1>
<form onsubmit="return signup();" method="post" name="subform"  id="subform" action="">
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td colspan=2><span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">Subscribe to     our newsletter</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size=2 face=Arial>Name:</font></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"  value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font size=2 face=Arial>Email:</font></td>
<td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align=right>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right" style="height:20px">&nbsp;
    <div id="myResponse" style="DISPLAY:none;"></div>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="wait.gif" alt=""></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my php file

```
    <?php
    header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    /*  ***************
    Attention: you shoul use your own function here to 
    purify the requested parameters and protect against injections.
    Example: $email = clean_this($_REQUEST["email"]);
    */
    $email  = trim($_REQUEST["email"]);
    $name   = trim($_REQUEST["name"]);

    /*
SAVING NAME AND EMAIL TO A TXT FILE
Create a myemails.txt file and put it in the same directory.
    */  

    $email  = trim($_REQUEST["email"]);
    $name   = trim($_REQUEST["name"]);
    $pfileName  = "myemails.txt";
    $MyFile     = fopen($pfileName, "a");
    $nline=$email.','.$name."\r\n";     
    // USE THIS TO SAVE ONLY THE EMAIL: $nline=$email."\r\n";
    fwrite($MyFile, $nline);
    fclose($MyFile);
    echo 'Thanks for Subscribing';  // Change the message if you want.
    die;
    ?>
```

I've tried deleting parts of the file that say $name but the form loses its ability to give feedback on a bad email or successful submission.

I would appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Is this the exact code or did you modify it for SO? If this is exact, just remove the `if (name=="")` in your js.

Comment: I've tried removing this section of the javascript but the form loses its e-mail validation for some reason....

Answer (score 1):

delete this:

```
<tr>
<td><font size=2 face=Arial>Name:</font></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"  value=""></td>
</tr>
```

and this:

```
var name    = trim($F("name"));

if (name=="") {
  // stuff
}
```

You should be able to remove other 'name' references in the JavaScript as well.

Change things like this:

```
$("name", "email").invoke('clear');
```

to:

```
$("email").invoke('clear');
```

The php file will be this:

```
<?php
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// fetch the email and add it to the file
$email  = trim($_REQUEST["email"]);
$pfileName  = "myemails.txt";
$MyFile     = fopen($pfileName, "a");   
$nline=$email."\r\n";
fwrite($MyFile, $nline);
fclose($MyFile);
echo 'Thanks for Subscribing';  // Change the message if you want.
die;
?>
```

Comment: Should I edit any of the Javascript at the top of my index.html?

Comment: yeah, if you want the same exactly JavaScript behavior, you'll want to change that as well.  I've updated my original post.

Comment: Hi Kery, Thanks for your help on this, I've removed all the parts you said from index.html and changed the contents of my .php file but the form loses any email validation and successful subscription message. I don't mind starting from scratch if there is a simple php file that does what I need that you know of? Im just after a really simple way of having a newsletter signup form that makes sure the email is valid, lets the user know their submission was successful and uploads the emails to a .txt file.

Comment: Possibly some javascript hanging around breaking things.  I would recommend looking at your javascript console to see if there are any errors.  You can run it in chrome/firefox with cmd + option + i (ctrl + shift + i on pc).  Click resources and then navigate to your html/javascript file and see if it's throwing any errors.

Comment: Cool, so I'm looking at my javascript console the first error was Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else index.html:16 so I changed if else to if on line 16. Now the form is almost working perfectly it notifies the user if they enter an invalid e-mail. If the user enters a valid email address it writes that email to the .txt file but says undefined instead of the thankyou for you submission message... the console says: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'invoke' index.html:46 - Almost there, on line 46 it reads: $("email").invoke('clear');Thnks 4 ur hlp so far:-)

Comment: not sure why that isn't working but you can remove the invoke and just add $('#myResponse').html('Thanks for Subscribing');  Which will add that text to the myResponse html div